# how to create VCard in window phone 7 using C#

Tags: c#-3.0

how to create VCard in window phone 7 using C# 
is it Possible to create VCard in window phone 7 ?

Comment: its not specifically for Wp7 but might help this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/08/09/creating-vcard-with-image-in-net.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is no inbuilt library for vcard in windows phone .

Try this link might help [CodeProject](http://vcardlibrary.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)